# CURL Error while making request: SSL connect error (error code: 35)

Tags: php, curl, webdav, sabredav

When I try to connect to BigCommerce's WebDAV server from PHP, I get the following error message:

> CURL Error while making request: SSL connect error (error code: 35)

I am using the SabreDAV Client library for PHP which is a wrapper around cURL.

I get the same error if I use curl from the command line.

I am using CentOS 6.3, PHP 5.3.3, curl 7.19.7.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on several different machines:

```
curl -v https://www.example.com/
```

On some machines I got the SSL error 35, and on some it worked with no error message. From this I suspected that there was some difference in the curl version being used, or else the related packages for SSL certs. So I tried updating some packages on the server I needed. It turned out that updating the Network Security Services (NSS) package fixed the problem.

```
yum update nss
```

Comment: Why you ask question to answer?

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski: That’s usually fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @minitech, hopefully someone will find it useful. A few months ago I spent more than a day searching for an answer to this and failed. Today I had to work on it again, and I found a solution.